# Angular - Child component gets destroyed after data change, why?

Tags: angular, lifecycle

I don't understand on which purpose child components are getting destroyed in Angular when data is changed.

Here's the case:

I have a parent and a child component:

**parent.component.html**

```
<div class="parent-content" (click)="toggleChild()">
   // ...
</div>
<child></child>
```

By clicking on the content the child will be toggled (child component will be shown by animation)

**parent.component.ts**

Here I'm subscribing to the sharedService data changes in my parent...

```
ngOnInit () {
    let subscription = this.sharedService.myData.subscribe( (data) => {
        this.data = data;
    });
}
```

.. as well as in my child (actually the child is wrapper for a dynamically created component, so to be accurate - I'm using the sharedService in my grand-child)

**child.component.ts**

```
this.resolver.resolveComponent(component).then(factory => {
     let componentRef = this.childContainer.createComponent(factory);
});
```

**grand-child.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit () {
    let subscription = this.sharedService.myData.subscribe( (data) => {
        this.data = data;
    });
}
```

Now when **myData** changes (due to server response) the child gets destroyed!
I'm losing all the data of the grand-child because it gets destroyed too!

I read about the component interaction [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html) and still can't figure out when exactly ngOnDestroy will be called, since I don't have any @Inputs...

Maybe I could store the grand-child manipulated data somewhere else before it gets destroyed, but the point is that I need this view to stay open *and* getting myData updated for parent and grand-child. Thanks for your help!

**UPDATE**

I've noticed that it actually doesn't matter that the child (grand-child) *shares* the data but the **sheer change of the parent data** causes the destruction (or re-initialization, because the child constructor is called again after destroy) of the child component. How is this problem solved?

Comment: `*ngIf`, `*ngFor`, route change

Comment: So what is the right approach for this problem? Pls look at the update above.

Comment: Sorry, not enough information to see what's going on. I see you create components dynamically but from the code in your question it's impossible for me to see how things are connected.

Comment: According to my update, it is a general purpose question. The parent and the child are not created dynamically, but in a standard way. I'm subscribing to data changes in the parent and as soon as this data changes the child is reinitialized (destroy, init), so the child is closed and opened again which I didn't intended.

Comment: In general the children are not destroyed on data change - except when for example an `*ngIf` condition becomes wrong and removes it's content. I guess this is why it's hard for me to understand the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that @GünterZöchbauer was right. My child components *were* inside an `*ngFor` at the top of my parent template which was depending on `myData`. Of course the `*ngFor` gets rerendered after a change and so did my child components. I restructed my views by pulling the child components out of the loop and placed them independently into the app while still loading them from a higher level component dynamically. Since they rely on the  `sharedService` they still get the data properly and stay open after change. Thanks!